# Schedule monthly task using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a task on a particular day of the month at a particular time. The interval between each run can be set between 1 and 12 months. In java, the tasks can be scheduled at fixed interval using ScheduledExecutorService. Since number of days in a month is not fixed, how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re running in a Java EE environment, you should use a [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) or the [@Schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) annotation.  But since you’re discussing ScheduledExecutorService, whose use is not permitted in a Java EE container, I’ll assume you are not running in one.

When using a ScheduledExecutorService, you can have the task itself schedule the next iteration:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = /* ... */ ;

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        long delay = now.until(now.plusMonths(1), ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            executor.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
};

int dayOfMonth = 5;

ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
if (dateTime.getDayOfMonth() >= dayOfMonth) {
    dateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(1);
}
dateTime = dateTime.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);
executor.schedule(task,
    ZonedDateTime.now().until(dateTime, ChronoUnit.MILLIS),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In versions of Java earlier than 8, you can use a Calendar to do the same thing:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = /* ... */ ;

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        long delay =
            calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            executor.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
};

int dayOfMonth = 5;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= dayOfMonth) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
executor.schedule(task,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis(),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want something that executes once in a long while, you'll need something reliable.

Take a look at Quartz:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/MonthlyTrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

In JavaEE with @Schedule annotation use `Last` keyword.
example :

```
@Schedule(second = "59", minute = "59", hour = "23", dayOfMonth = "Last", persistent = false)
```