# Run a task every month on 1st day of the month using ScheduledExecutorService in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to schedule a task on 1st of every month using Scheduled Executer service in spring boot. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a timer task on a specific day (1st of every month) using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501503/run-a-timer-task-on-a-specific-day-1st-of-every-month-using-spring)

Comment: No, I wanna do the same but with scheduledexecutorservice. not with cron

Comment: Maybe [schedule-monthly-task-using-scheduledexecutorservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021895/schedule-monthly-task-using-scheduledexecutorservice) can help you.

Comment: NO it's not working